# Unique counting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

**UPDATED:**

I have data where QA team have records and QC team have records. Im trying to add how many attempts they do on each record they work on. This should count to the "Attempts" column and how how many times the RecordName for each team (QA/QC) was worked on.

This is what i have tried:

```
with counts as (
  select [GTNUM],[RecordName],[Type],[Status], COUNT(*) row_count
    from QATAT 
    group by [GTNUM],[RecordName],[Type],[Status]
),
results as (
  select d.[RecordName],d.[Type], counts.row_count, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.[RecordName] order by d.[RecordName] ) row_num
    from QATAT d
      inner join counts on counts.[RecordName] = d.[RecordName]
)
select [RecordName],[Type], row_count, max(row_num) AS Attempts
  from results  
  group by [RecordName],[Type], row_count
  order by [RecordName];
```

This is how it should look:

```
+--------+------------+------+--------+----------+
| GTNUM  | RecordName | Type | Status | Attempts |
+--------+------------+------+--------+----------+
| 334455 | REC6456    | QA   | Fail   |        1 |
| 334455 | REC6456    | QC   | Fail   |        2 |
| 334455 | REC6456    | QC   | Pass   |        2 |
| 465456 | REC9872    | QA   | Pass   |        1 |
| 784158 | REC1111    | QC   | Fail   |        1 |
| 451248 | REC9634    | QC   | Fail   |        1 |
+--------+------------+------+--------+----------+
```

Nothing I am trying seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read this:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: My info at the top is how it should look once i run the code, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple `GROUP BY` could solve your problem:

```
SELECT 
    GTNUM  
   ,RecordName 
   ,Type 
   ,Status 
   ,COUNT(*) Attempts 

FROM Tablename
GROUP BY
    GTNUM  
   ,RecordName 
   ,Type 
   ,Status
```

Comment: The Attempts column is what i am trying to add, it is currently not there and i am trying to add this.

Comment: That was one of the few clear things in the question :) try it please, then come back with any further question if needed

Comment: My humble apologies, I have updated all now. my bad, sorry for the poor post at first.

Comment: I just want to find out if what im saying here makes sense or should i make a new question and articulate it differently?